# What Paragon-Tier modules can I use to showcase the Underdark?

Tags: dnd-4e, game-recommendation, campaign-settings, published-adventures, paragon-tier

My group is going through the Underdark top to bottom to get to Menzoberranzan. I'm looking for recommendations for Underdark themed modules - starting with near-the-surface (no- or lite-Drow) dungeon crawls, some exploring (the FeyDark?) and leading to heavy-Drow intrigue. An encounter with Lolth seems likely, after a few levels gained.

It's all new to me, and I haven't ready *any* of the novels - neither have my players. I've never ran anything in the Underdark or the Planes. I already own the 4E Underdark and Menzoberranzan source books - lots of material, but they are not modules. They will have a Drow guide with them, if that matters.

Ideal criteria (in rough order):

1. Take place in, and heavily feature, the Underdark (Shallows, FeyDark and Menzoberranzan)
2. D&D 4e (comparable 3rd Party modules welcome)
3. Paragon Tier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demon Queen's Enclave](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910071944/http://archive.wizards.com/DnD/Product.aspx?x=dnd/products/dndacc/217827400) is an adventure set in a Drow settlement in the Underdark aimed to take characters from14th to 17th level. I've played through it as a player and found it was less railroaded than some other 4th Edition published adventures.